# Vagrant DB box - what are the best practices?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Our production servers setup is quite standard:
API + WEB + DB servers.

The API is mainly the one to access the DB, but the WEB does that also in certain cases.

I want to create a similar local setup using Vagrant.

**This is where I got so far:**

I have 2 git projects, a WEB and an API.
I turned them into Vagrant projects, by putting a Vagrantfile in both main directories.. each Vagrantfile points to a dedicated box which includes all the server dependencies.

Both VM's take the code from the mounted vagrant folder. So far - it works like a charm.

Now, i've got to the point where I need to create a VM for the DB, the thing is.. I obviosuly don't have DB git project - where do I put the Vagrantfile in this case? It's very convenient that the Vagrantfile is part of the code.

What are the best practices?

I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would see 2 possibilities:

1. anyway, create another Vagrantfile just for the DB even if you do not have code associated, you can still have a git project only for the Vagrantfile.
   The downside is that you need to start vagrant from 3 different files, so not the best
2. put the DB VM into one of API or WEB (maybe WEB would make more sense but depends your project) so when will start 2 VM from the same Vagrantfile.